# Laravel 4 Redirects aren't working

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-4

I am attempting to use `return Redirect::route('home');` in my UserController, but it doesn't appear to work (displays a blank page). I've tried naming the route, but to no avail.

```
<?php

class UserController extends BaseController {

    public $restful = true;

    public function get_new()
    {
           return View::make('users.new')
                ->with('title', 'Rentaholics - Register');     
    }

    public function post_create() {
        $validation = Users::validate(Input::all());

        if($validation -> passes()){
            Users::create(array(
                'username'=>Input::get('username'),
                'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
                'email'=>Input::get('email')
            ));

            return Redirect::to_route('home')->with('message', 'Thanks for Registering!');
        }else{
                 return Redirect::to('register')->with_errors($validation)->with_input();
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: So I guess your `home`-route just returns nothing / a blank page... What are you expecting to see?

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: Im expecting to see my home view, its outlined in the routes.php as Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@get_index'));

Comment: <?php

Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@get_index'));
                                                                                           Route::get('register', array('as' => 'register', 'uses' =>  'UserController@get_new'));

Route::post('register', array('uses' => 'UserController@post_create'));

Comment: Just noticed that the return statement is within the `if`-condition. So if the validation fails, you're not being redirected anywhere and just get a blank page in return. You should at least redirect back to the post_create-route, and also tack on the error messages so the user knows what's wrong.

Comment: I've completed everything however whenever i click on my register button it is saying "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed"

Comment: I don't know what `Users::validate()` does and what it returns, but since the controller-code seems fine, I guess the problem will be there. So you'll have to show that, too. And by the way: Even though snake_case is acceptable, camelCase is the preferred PSR-2 notation for method names and should also be consistently used in Laravel. (https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#a3-survey-results)